# How does optimization of final references work in java?

Tags: java, optimization, compilation

I'd been trying to figure out all about Java optimizations and found something interesting.

**First case: primitive type compile-time optimization**

```
public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int i = 300;
        new Clazz() {
            void foo() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }.foo();
    }
}
```

After compilation (I'm using `jd-gui-0.3.5.windows` to decompile binary files) it is looks like:

```
public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 300;
        new Clazz() {
            void foo() {
                System.out.println(300);
            }
        }.foo();
    }
}
```

As expected, isn't it? `i` was replaced with it's value (inlining optimization) after compilation. So, I expected to see something similar after replacing primitive type with it's wrapper, but...

**Second case: non-primitive type compile-time optimization**

```
public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final Integer i = 300; // replaced int with Integer
        new Clazz() {
            void foo() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }.foo();
    }
}
```

After compilation:

```
public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(300);
        new Clazz() {
            void foo() {
                System.out.println(Clazz.this);
            }
        }.foo();
    }
}
```

### Questions:

What is `Clazz.this` in this context? I know, that it is reference to enclosing instance of `Clazz`, but it should not work in that case! I need to print `i`, but compiler suggests me to print `Clazz.this` instead of it and it works! What is the problem? Does `jd-gui` decompiles incorrectly or do I missing something about Java compilation and optimization?

**UPD:**

Content of `Class$1`:

```
class Clazz$1 extends Clazz {
    Clazz$1(Integer paramInteger) {}

    void foo() {
        System.out.println(this.val$i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the decompiled code of `Clazz$1` also? that might be the clue to `System.out.println(Clazz.this)`. Because it might be possible that `Clazz$1` might be containing `toString()` method where it is returning `i`

Comment: plz put code for `clazz$1` also.!

Comment: @VishalK jd-gui does not show the anonymous class separately, it reincludes it in the enclosing class.

Comment: @assylias actually it shows

Comment: @zvzdhk Ah I understand - I was looking at the generated jar directly, in which case jd-gui reinjects tha anonymous class - if you look at the class files directly you get what you posted.

Comment: @assylias yes, I decompile files separately :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does `jd-gui` decompiles incorrectly or do I missing something about Java compilation and optimization?

`jd-gui` is decompiling the code incorrectly.

On my JVM, the disassembled code for the anonymous class looks as follows:

```
class Clazz$1 extends Clazz {
  Clazz$1(java.lang.Integer);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_1       
       2: putfield      #10                 // Field val$i:Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: aload_0       
       6: invokespecial #12                 // Method Clazz."<init>":()V
       9: return        

  void foo();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #20                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: aload_0       
       4: getfield      #10                 // Field val$i:Ljava/lang/Integer;
       7: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      10: return        
}
```

As you can see, a copy of `i` stored in the anonymous class, in the field called `val$i` (the name is implementation-specific).

It is this field that your decompiler appears to incorrectly render as `Clazz.this`.

Comment: It is should be a nearest approach which `jd-gui` miss interpret how `Integer` object out-boxing its value when `System.out.println` was invoked. Decompile algorithm itself must presume what is the most significant reference to this Integer object and it pick result of Clazz.this.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply have a look at the bytecode (`javap -c Clazz$1.class`).

With `int i = 300`:

```
void foo();
   0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: sipush        300
   6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   9: return
```

With `Integer i = 300`:

```
void foo();
   0: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: aload_0
   4: getfield      #1                  // Field val$i:Ljava/lang/Integer;
   7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  10: return
```

So the `int` is inlined but the `Integer` is not.

---

Also for the record, this is what I get from jd-gui (3.0.5):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer i = Integer.valueOf(300);
  new Clazz() {
    void foo() {
      System.out.println(this.val$i);
    }
  }
  .foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is should be a nearest approach which `jd-gui` miss interpret how `Integer` object out-boxing its value when `System.out.println` was invoked. Decompile algorithm itself must presume what is the most significant reference to this `Integer` object and it pick result of `Clazz.this`.